# Firefox Addin - View and kill windows processes

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, process

I am looking for a FireFox addin that allows you to view and kill a certain windows process.
I have Googled and looked everywhere and I cannot find one.

Comment: What on earth do you hope to achieve with this, when you can do it with Process Explorer, to name just *one* app?

Comment: A firefox addin which will kill windows process ? I don't think you can stop a windows progress from firefox.

Comment: @Randolph Potter - hell ... windows are actually pretty good at stopping processes on their own ;-)

Comment: @Tom - or did you mean, maybe, to stop a windows process, as in some process (a script or something) in a firefox window, i.e. tab ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question, just in case we're misunderstanding you - what are you expecting to accomplish that you can't do by simply going into Task Manager using CTRL+SHIFT+ESC?

Comment: I am on a limited user account at school and a few programs keep crashing and will not close. I need to kill them via a "Process Killer" because they are slowing the system as they crash. And the IS department wont fix these issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for multi-process features within the browser, similar Google Chrome's [Task Manager](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html), this does not yet exist for Firefox, but work is [in progress](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis). Ars Technica have a good [summary](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/07/firefox-stability-to-get-a-boost-with-multiprocess-browsing.ars) of the planned architecture and progress as of mid 2009.